# running perl script with python

Tags: python

let say, 
I have a perl scipt on UNIX:
 trial.pl

```
print ("hello" world);
```

and python is on window: 
Python SCipt:

```
subprocess.call("perl trial.pl",shell=True)
```

it print "1" in the GUI which means false, why?

Comment: There's a typo in the first Perl script.

Comment: Have you tried running the perl script? There is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

It will return zero if the perl script is executed successfully

```
>>> rc = subprocess.call('perl /tmp/t.pl', shell=True)
Hello world
>>> rc
0
```

So if you get a return 1, it means either `perl` cannot find the `trial.pl` file (you need to specify absolute path to fix it) or there is a problem within your perl script file (you can run it independently to verify)

Comment: ,I can run the script on the UNIX,but not on window, the path for the file is rc=subprocess.call('perl \\sbsamba1b\msbpehome1$\trial.pl',shell=True), but it always return false

Comment: You have to mount the \\sbsamba1b\msbpehome1$ to a drive, says z:, then run it as 'perl z:/trial.pl'